# How to avoid assigning the same GameObject individually for every prefab?

Tags: unity

In many times, prefabs that share the same script may require the same GameObject in the script. For example, in my game I want to make a series of card prefabs. Each card has their own image when shown, but has the same back image when hidden. My script for card is:

```
public class DraggingCard : DragAndDropItem
{
    public Sprite secretSprite; //This is the same for every card
    Sprite oringinalSprite; //This is individual for every card
    Image image;

    public void Awake()
    {
        image = GetComponent<Image>();
        oringinalSprite = image.sprite;
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        image.sprite = oringinalSprite;
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        image.sprite = secretSprite;
    }
}
```

But if I write this, I'll have to assign the `secretSprite` in the inspector for every DraggingCard prefab. I tried to set `secretPrefab` to be `static` or `const` but neither worked.

I believe there must be a clever way to avoid the repeat work. Could anyone tell me that? Thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm if your objects containing `DraggingCard` are all instances of the same prefab, or if there are multiple base prefabs?

Comment: @Gnemlock There are multiple prefabs. Each of the prefab has an `Image` whose sprite is `originalSprite`, and is attached with a `DraggingCard` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and cheapest method is to do it all in one go.

**Select all of your prefabs** in your project window (you can use search to get them all in one view, even if they're in different folders), and then assign the field once. The newly assigned value will be applied to every prefab in your selection.

Most scripts you write in Unity will support this type of multi-editing out of the box. [If using a custom editor you might need to do a little work to enable this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanEditMultipleObjects.html).

---

Some alternatives you can use if you need something more elaborate:

**A)** In your `Start` script, load the texture you want with `Resources.Load` - you pass a path to the texture from a folder called Resources, which can be a static string. Just note that anything in a Resource folder will always be included in your build, even if you stop using it, and Unity won't be able to see this reference to pre-load the assets you need, so loading a lot of assets this way can introduce a performance hit.

**B)** Introduce an object with a "Manager" script into your scene, where the manager's job is to keep track of common references other scripts need. In `Start`, your other scripts can find the manager with built-in `Find` methods or a static `GetInstance` method, and ask it for their references. That way you only need to assign the references once to the manager object's prefab.

Comment: Thank you! I'm now temporarily fixing it with `Resources.Load`, but it makes annoyed that I have to explicitly put sprites that I want every prefab to share in the folder...

Comment: Did you try just doing it with multi-select? It's a more scalable solution unless you find some obstacle to doing it that way.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you! I don't have enough rep to vote you up though....

Comment: No worries, I've got all the rep I need. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Assign the script and the secretSprite to your DraggingCard object before you make it a prefab. Then every DraggingCard instance that you place in your scene will already have the secretSprite assigned to it.

Comment: Because you've already made your prefab, just select one of the DraggingCard instances in your scene that you've already assigned the sercretSprite to, and click the 'Apply' button in the inspector- that will update the prefab object itself and apply the changes to any existing instances of the prefab that you have in your scene.

Comment: I think this question is about having more than one prefab. (For example, if I have a deck of cards with a prefab for AceOfClubs and TwoOfClubs and...) - so the scene instances aren't all sharing a single root prefab.

Comment: In that example though, all of the cards are essentially the same object, they just need a different sprite assigned for their face (something you would probably assign at run time using the output of your shuffling/card selection algorithm). The back of the card, or in this case the 'secretSprite' is presumably one sprite shared by each individual card.

Comment: reversing my vote. `DraggingCard` being a script, there is no guarantee that all cards will be the same object.

Comment: Whether or not the OP chooses to have all of the cards based on the same object is really more of a design choice than a fundamental problem with the proposed solution, but each to their own. In terms of design choices though, having individual prefabs for each individual rank and suit of card is probably a poor one, as it really fails to take advantage of the power and convenience offered by prefabs and object orientated design in the first place. The OP inquired about a more efficient approach to his problem, to which their are probably multiple alternatives to choose from.

Comment: Maybe someone would think it is better to make only one Card prefab, and assign each of the Card objects their own sprite and values when spawned, but I don't think this is better than making a prefab for each card, because it is just a difference on either you do more dirty work in the code or in the inspector...from the view of a Unity beginner.

Comment: True.The time it costs to create each prefab manually for objects that differ only on a single attribute, and (in larger scale projects) the potential additional overhead created by this approach is why I don't like doing it that way, but for a card game where your assets and overall project size aren't that big/numerous to begin with it's probably not a big deal really. The handy multi select tip from @DMGregory helps out there too. Just a design choice and difference of opinion. Best of luck on your project @DarkZero!